# What is my internet speed?

Tags: router, modem, isp, adsl, internet-speed

**First three days** The speed in the **Router** *"192.168.1.1"* is **5 mbit** all the time, and in **speedtest.net is 5 mbit**.

[image: router]

[image: test5]

**After 3 days** The speed in **speedtest.net** *dropped to* **4 mbit**, but still **5 mbit in the Router**.

[image: test4]

> Notes:
>
> **I test speed** in Router and Speedtest **every 3 hours** and the **results are similar**, then the speed dropped, no edit in Router or PC or Cable.
>
> The **Router does not** test speed by download file like Speedtest, **it get speed from ISP**.

```
Router    : TP-Link
WAN       : ADSL2+ PPPoE
DSL cable : cat4 50 meter

PC        : core i5
OS        : Ubuntu 18.4.1
Browser   : Chrome 68
Program   : no other programs use internet at test time
LAN       : only me connected to the router
WLAN      : desabled
LAN cable : cat5e 2 meter
```

Which one actual my speed (**Router** or **Speedtest**) ?

Comment: The router is showing the current network usage, not your maximum speed. If speedtest.net test uses 4mbps but router shows 5, there is probably something else in your network that uses 1mbps at the time you checked.

Comment: I make sure before the test that is not something that uses the Internet

Comment: I test every 3 hours 3 or 4 times

Comment: In that case it might just be slight difference in display. Your router shows the maximum data that was put through at that moment while speedtest.net always shows a sort-of average as test result.

Comment: The speed was stable at five and then dropped to 4, and also stable at 4, which means that the site measures well with a slight difference in results

Comment: I feel that the ISP is stealing and reducing the speed

Comment: @confetti: No, ADSL modems _do_ show the maximum rate this way. "Max Rate" is what physical conditions allow, and "Data Rate" is what was negotiated with the DSLAM according to your plan.

Comment: All the Routers/Modem provided by this ISP show the speed

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I thought "Max rate" is the physical allowance and "data rate" is what's being used at the moment. In that case, 5mbps is the maximum you can reach. There can be multiple factors why this isn't always what you get on speedtest.net. Latency to their servers plays a role here too, but I'd say you're close enough to what your ISP promises.

Comment: 4m not close to 5m !!!

Comment: Look at your router stats for line rate (Status > DSL). That is the max speed of your connection.

Comment: Look at first picture

Comment: Have you tried something other than speedtest.net? What's your speed for example when downloading from a torrent? That, given enough peers, usually gives me slightly higher and more accurate values than speedtest.net.

Comment: Yes, torrent and idm and chrome and linux , all programs show 5m at begin then dropped to 4m after 3 days

Comment: You should probably test at the same time each day if you want to determine why this is happening. Perhaps 10am is quite an active time in your region and 7pm is not so much?